# Tensorflow BahdanauAttention - Layer memory_layer expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

> Tensorflow: 1.12

I am using `bidirectional_dynamic_rnn`. I wrote `encoder_output` to BahdanauAttention's memory option (recommended on tensorflow website), but it throws an error:

> ValueError: Layer memory_layer expects 1 inputs, but it received 2
>   input tensors. Inputs received: tf.Tensor
>   'bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/transpose_1:0' shape=(?, ?, 512)
>   dtype=float32, tf.Tensor 'ReverseSequence:0' shape=(?, ?, 512)
>   dtype=float32]

```
def model_inputs():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='input')
    targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='target')
    lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='learning_rate')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
    return inputs, targets, lr, keep_prob

def preprocess_targets(targets, word2int, batch_size):
    left_side = tf.fill([batch_size, 1], word2int['<SOS>'])
    right_side = tf.strided_slice(targets, [0,0], [batch_size, -1], [1,1])
    preprocessed_targets = tf.concat([left_side, right_side], 1)
    return preprocessed_targets

#Encoder RNN
def encoder_rnn(rnn_inputs, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, sequence_lenght):
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
    lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, input_keep_prob = keep_prob)
    encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout] * num_layers)
    global encoder_output, encoder_state
    encoder_output, encoder_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw = encoder_cell,
                                                                    cell_bw = encoder_cell,
                                                                    sequence_length = sequence_length,
                                                                    inputs = rnn_inputs,
                                                                    dtype = tf.float32)

    return encoder_state



#Decoding training set
def decode_training_set(encoder_state, decoder_cell, decoder_embedded_input, sequence_lenght, decoding_scope, output_function, keep_prob, batch_size):
    #attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, decoder_cell.output_size])
    attention_mechanism = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention(num_units = decoder_cell.output_size, memory = encoder_output, normalize=False)
```

What can I do?

Comment: A complete stack trace would probably help to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: Hi @iga I have edited and that's all. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't see the full stack trace that includes all the calls leading to the error.

Comment: I think the memory_layer of attention mechanism is expecting only one tensor as output from encoding layer at each step (as in the natural case of only one directional encoder_rnn). Somehow, either we have to concat both the forward and backward outputs or provide a single tensor with features of both the forward and backward outputs.